# Nginx: Static files encoding utf8 character results in Ã

Tags: file, ubuntu, utf-8, nginx

Im trying to figure out why nginx is trying load some static images with the wrong encoding. E.g.:

From the **error.log**:

> 2012/08/08 21:14:46 [error] 17968#0: *71 open()
>   "/home/www/mydomain.com/WEB-INF/images/productimage/image-Ã¸.png"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server:
>   www.mydomain.com, request: "GET /images/productimage/image-%C3%B8.png
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "www.mydomain.com", referrer:
>   "http://www.mydomain.com/"

In my nginx.conf file i added the following;

```
source_charset utf-8;
charset utf-8;
```

But unfortunately, that didnt solve it.

My vhost config file uses the following to serve the image files;

```
    location /images/
    {
            alias /home/www/mydomain.com/WEB-INF/images/;
            expires 15d;
    }
```

I'm using ubuntu, with the LANG environment variables set as such;

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Any clue ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percent-encoding in URIs is really two steps of encoding, not one. Ideally, first text is encoded as UTF-8, and the UTF-8 text is "percent-encoded" to be used in a URI, producing a result like this:

```
/images/productimage/image-%C3%B8.png
```

Can you confirm that this URI has been encoded properly? If you start with the character you want, and then encode it as UTF-8 and then percent-encode it, is the result %C3%B8? You can manually generate a percent-encoded script like this:

```
 $perl -MCGI -e 'print CGI::escape("Hello World")."\n";'
 Hello%20World
```

Another way to put it: Are your sure the problem is in the *decoding* by Nginx, and not the *encoding*? Check the encoding of the HTML page that contains the image reference. Review both the HTTP headers and the meta tags. Make sure it explicitly declares itself as UTF-8. Otherwise, that could be cause for the browser to mis-interpret the reference.

You can likewise manually test the decoding process, like this:

```
 perl -MCGI -e 'print CGI::unescape("/images/productimage/image-%C3%B8.png")."\n";'
 /images/productimage/image-ø.png
```

I've written a [detailed post about percent-encoding with Perl](http://mark.stosberg.com/blog/2010/12/percent-encoding-uris-in-perl.html), if that's of interest as a reference.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reply, i've tested the unescaping via perl via your last command line, and perl also seems to output: /images/productimage/image-Ã¸.png instead of the desired /images/productimage/image-ø.png, it seems that your suggestion is right, using the encoding /images/productimage/image-%F8.png does load the image, so whats determining the default decoding character set in the case of perl/ nginx ?

Comment: Marius, I've added this to my answer: "Check the encoding of the HTML page that contains the image reference. Review both the HTTP headers and the meta tags. Make sure it explicitly declares itself as UTF-8. Otherwise, that could be cause for the browser to mis-interpret the reference."

Comment: Thats part of a solution, but in this case, i am wondering, when i call the url directly from the browser, not included in an html page, urlencoded with %C3%B8, what configures the character set used for decoding, nginx, or a configurable in ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think it matters, the characters should have always been encoded as UTF-8 before they were percent-encoded, so the only correct way to interpret them is to presume UTF-8 when decoding. That's why in Perl's URI::Escape module, you have two escaping functions depending on whether our not your input has already been encoded with UTF-8, but there is only one "unescape" function. Are your certain that %C3%B8 is correct result when your target character is represented in UTF-8 and then percent-encoded?